# What means number on number?

Tags: notation

What does the following notation mean?

$$k \choose n$$

If you didn't understand me see my question and the first answer that was accepted [Permutation and combinations using chairs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805753/permutation-and-combinations-using-chairs)

Comment: It means [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question a second time. There is in fact an answer in the comment when you asked the first time here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807796/what-mean-number-on-number-in-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\binom{n}{r}=nCr=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$
$$\text{Where }x!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot x$$
E.g.
$$\binom{7}{5}=\frac{7!}{5!\cdot2!}=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7}{(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5)\cdot(1\cdot2)}=\frac{6\cdot7}{2}=21$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to read

$${n \choose r}$$

is "*n* choose *r*" -- it's the number of ways to choose a group of $r$ things out of $n$ things. The order of the things once you've chosen them doesn't matter.

Rhys' answer has the formula for this.